# Android UI Thread Block when calling AsynchTask.get()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, ui-thread

My activity is a login page. When the user clicks, an asyncTask check in a database if credentials are good. During the task, I want to display a ProgressDialog but after clicking on the button, it stays pressed for 5 seconds and then my ProgressDialog quiclky shows up (less than 1 second) and the toast appears.

There is my onClick function :

```
Button connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
final EditText loginED = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
final EditText passwordED = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    String login = loginED.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordED.getText().toString();
    String[] params = {login, password};

    DoAsyncLogin doAsyncLogin = new DoAsyncLogin();
        try {
        String result = doAsyncLogin.execute(params).get();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
});
```

And my AsyncTask :

```
private class DoAsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
ProgressDialog connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return getLoginData(params);
}

protected void onPreExecute(){

    connectionProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
    connectionProgressDialog.show();
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    connectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are waiting (blocking) for the **AsynchTask** to finish its execution on the main thread ( which makes it useless ):
**See the documentations for AsynchTask get method here** :[AsynchTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Instead you should use `onPostExcute` call back to get your results.

Code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

   String login = loginED.getText().toString();
   String password = passwordED.getText().toString();
   String[] params = {login, password};

   DoAsyncLogin doAsyncLogin = new DoAsyncLogin();
   doAsyncLogin.execute(params);
}
```

and in your asynchTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
  connectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```